# Shader creation Opengl

Tags: opengl, shader

I am using OpenGl 3 and the tutorial from BennyBox on Youtube.

Using this method:

```
static void CheckShaderError(GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool isProgram, const std::string& errorMessage){
    GLint success = 0;
    GLchar error [1024] = {0};

    if(isProgram){
        glGetProgramiv(shader, flag, &success);
    }else{
        glGetShaderiv(shader, flag, &success);
    }
    if(success == GL_FALSE){
        if(isProgram){
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(error), NULL, error);
        }else{
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader,sizeof(error), NULL, error);
        }
        std::cerr<< errorMessage<< ": " << error<< "'"<<std::endl; 
    }
}
```

I should be able to load shader file (fragment and vertex shaders). It works with basic shaders but when I try to modify them to that point:

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec2 texCoord;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
}
```

The I get:

```
Error compiling shader!: 'ERROR: 0:6: 'texCoord' : redefinition
ERROR: 0:11: 'texCoord0' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:11: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'attribute 2-component vector of float' to 'float'
```

and the fragment shader:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D diffuse;
varying vec2 texCoord0;

void main(){ 
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(diffuse, texCoord0);
}
```

gives:

```
Unable to load shader: ./res/basicShader.fs
Error linking shader program: 'Attached vertex shader is not compiled.
```

I have the exact same code as the video, and it runs fine using basic coloring shader. I am on Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two errors in your vertex shader.

First, you are declaring texCoord twice.

```
attribute vec2 texCoord;
varying vec2 texCoord;
```

Then you are trying to use a varying called texCoord0, without ever declaring it.

```
texCoord0 = texCoord;
```

Your vertex shader should look like this:

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec2 texCoord0;

void main(){

    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
}
```

Comment: Alright that did it indeed. I realized I also had a typo for sample2D which should be sampler2d.I guess I did not follow thoroughly the tutorial...Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to help.